# ImageMagick PDF to JPEG conversion results in green square where image should be

Tags: pdf, imagemagick, jpeg

I'm attempting to convert a PDF to a JPEG using ImageMagick.

The PDF:
[`baby_aRCWTU.pdf`](http://classifieds.democratandchronicle.com/bab/baby_aRCWTU.pdf)

The command:
`convert -density 260 -profile 'SWOP.icc' -profile 'sRGB.icm' 'baby_aRCWTU.pdf' 'baby_aRCWTU.jpg'`

The resulting JPEG:
[`baby_aRCWTU.jpg`](http://classifieds.democratandchronicle.com/bab/baby_aRCWTU.jpg)

As you can see, the text is rendered nicely, but the embedded image shows up as a green square. Any ideas? This occurs with and without the colour profiles.

**edit:** reposted due to broken links

Comment: Are you seeing the same error in both IE and Mozilla? The reason I ask is because IE sees the MIME type for a JPEG as image/pjpeg instead of image/jpeg, which can cause some problems.

Comment: This is not a browser issue. Opening the files in a standalone PDF reader gives the same results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On a site we convert hundreds of PDF's on a daily basis where we need to create JPGs and we found it only reliable to convert the PDF's to postscript first.

We use the "pdftops" command, try

```
pdftops baby_aRCWTU.pdf baby_aRCWTU.ps
```

then your convert command above, but on the ps. Works for me, the image is then included.

Comment: I'm having a similar problem.  Is there a good equivalent to pdftops available for Windows?

Comment: Disclaimer (I work for Atalasoft) -- For Windows (.NET) Our PDF Reader add-on to DotImage can convert PDF to any image type http://atalasoft.com/products/dotimage