# How to generate image files from pdf using imagick?

Tags: php, imagick

Hi I am using `Imagick` php library to create an `thumbnail` for lots of `pdf` files.

My question is, how do I actually generate those image into an actual file. like test.jpg or test2.jpg.

My codes are as follow:

```
   $display           = array ('pdf');
    $directoryIterator = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator('/test/project');

    foreach (new RecursiveIteratorIterator($directoryIterator) as $fileName => $file) {

        $fileExtension = pathinfo($fileName, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

        if (in_array(strtolower($fileExtension), $display)) {
            if(file_exists($fileName)){
                 $im = new imagick($fileName.'[0]');
                 $im->setImageFormat("jpg");
                 echo $im;

            }
        }
    }
```

The codes have no errors but there is no `image` file being generated in the `/test/project/` folder. I was wondering if anyone can help me about it.

Comment: Did you try changing the image format to jpeg? Try `$im->setImageFormat('jpeg');`

Comment: i did. it's the same result. no file was being generated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to call the writeImage method on your Imagick object to have it actually write the file.

Replace `echo $im;` with:

```
$im->writeImage('thumb.jpg');
```

This question might have more info: [Convert PDF to JPEG with PHP and ImageMagick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9227014/convert-pdf-to-jpeg-with-php-and-imagemagick)