# convert pdf into jpg using exec

Tags: php, imagemagick, jpeg, converters

I want to convert a PDF-Image to a .JPG-Image.

I made a convert.php which i can call with the filename of the PDF file and convert it to jpg. I call this function like this: http://www.example.ch/tools/img/cache/convert.php?f=MyPdf.pdf

this looks like this:

```
if ($f = @$_REQUEST['f']) {
    $f = htmlspecialchars(urldecode($f));
    $url  = 'http://www.example.ch/img/cache/'.$f;


    $file = strtolower($f);

    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.1.2) Gecko/20090729 Firefox/3.5.2 GTB5');

    $data = curl_exec($ch);

    $retcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

    curl_close($ch);
    if ($retcode == 200) {
        file_put_contents($file, $data);
        $converted_filename = str_replace('.pdf', '.jpg', $file );
        $cmd = 'convert '.$file.' '.$converted_filename;
        exec('convert '.$file.' '.$converted_filename);
        $fp = fopen($converted_filename, 'rb');

        header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
        header("Content-Length: " . filesize($converted_filename));
        fpassthru($fp);
        exit;
    } else {
        header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
    }

}
```

After this is done i get an .jpg File with the size of 700KB in my folder and i can't open it because it is corrupted. And the HTML output is also like: The image can't be oppened because it contains errors..

Answer (score 0):

The best tool for above is ImageMagic.

Install Image magic in your system and refer this link

[Convert PDF to JPEG with PHP and ImageMagick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9227014/convert-pdf-to-jpeg-with-php-and-imagemagick)

It is very easy to do these kind of things Using ImageMagic. Also refer this link

http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.setimageformat.php

Hope this will solve your problem

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, convert is either part of, or uses, ImageMagick. Which uses Ghostscript to do the rendering of PDF files..... I can't really see that this is a Ghostscript question as it stands, it really ought to be an ImageMagick question.