# Image magic function giving fatal error in reading file

Tags: php, imagemagick

I'm getting error!!!

[image: fatal error]

here is my code

```
error_reporting(1);
ini_set('display_errors', 'on');
require_once "html2pdf/html2pdf.class.php";
$html_content = "<html lang='en'>
    <head> <title> Image </title> </head>
    <body> <h1> This is test, Now what do you want??? </h1> </body>
</html>";

$html2pdf = new HTML2PDF('P', 'A4');
$html2pdf->WriteHTML($html_content);
$file = $html2pdf->Output('temp.pdf', 'F');

$im = new imagick();
$im->setResolution(300,300);
$im->readimage('temp.pdf[0]');
$im->setImageFormat('jpeg');
$im->writeImage('thumb.jpg');
$im->clear();
$im->destroy();
```

getting error at this line of code `$im->readimage('temp.pdf[0]');`
I've search and find this link [Convert PDF to JPEG with PHP and ImageMagick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9227014/convert-pdf-to-jpeg-with-php-and-imagemagick) but this code is not working at my system using wamp server `PHP Version 5.4.16`, `Apache 2.4.4`, `wampserver 2.4`, `windows 7 32 bit` and `ImageMagick 6.8.6` so what is the problem in my code why it is giving me this error and how to solve this???

Comment: Can you please check with providing the full path for `temp.pdf`.

Comment: the file exists at my root directory the path is right I think the readimage function couldn't read pdf format `$im->readimage('temp.pdf[0]');`.

Comment: Yes true :), there is some issue, but not like `readimage` can't read from pdf files. It can. `Imagick` class can be used for reading from PDF files.

Comment: So you're talking about this
`$im = new imagick('temp.pdf');
    $im->setImageFormat('jpg');
    header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
    echo $im;`
I've also tried this but didn't work.