# Is there any way to make a pdf which cannot be converted to word?

Tags: php, pdf, yii, ms-word

We have a system which is generating PDF files. But anyone can convert those files using online pdf to word converter. Is there any option available in Yii or PHP to stop this?

Comment: have you tried to encode the file/text into image and then generate pdf using that generated image. This make the pdf can't be copied therefore can't be converted to word document

Comment: Nothing that can't be circumvented

Comment: I fail to see the point of why would someone want to do that. Seems to be an user limiting feature that achieves nothing (like disabling the right click on webpage). If you are afraid of forging documents under your name you should get certificate instead and digitally sign your pdfs.

Comment: @vove : that's not my requirement. Client's requirement

Comment: @TNC it obviously is impossible to prevent people from converting a Pdf to a word file, they can always take screenshots and add them to the word file as images, probably with some OCR applied. Thus, you should clarify with your client what exactly he wants too express with that requirement.

Answer (score 1):

To prevent PDF from been converted into Word you may:

1. Set password that is required to view PDF *- once password is shared - it can be removed*
2. Convert [PDF to images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9227014/convert-pdf-to-jpeg-with-php-and-imagemagick), then convert these images to PDF (using  [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/), [Ghostscript](http://www.ghostscript.com/)) *- recoverable using OCR.*
3. Write your code that damages so-called `CMAP`(`/ToUnicode` dictionary) inside generated PDF so the copied text will not match the text that is displayed to viewer *- but still recoverable using OCR.*
4. Use the [handwritten font](http://www.dafont.com/jenna-sue.font) for text that is [drawn into image](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagettftext.php). Then these images are saved as [JPEG](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php) and these JPEG files are converted into final PDF - *not recoverable using OCR but can be recovered using HWR*
5. Use [vector drawing](http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/line.htm) commands to draw your own letters line by line, so will look like letters but will not be recognized by PDF readers as text *- still recoverable using human eye.*
6. **Finally**, you may skip generating PDFs but instead print a physical document, make a hard cover for it and send by a physical post to your customers and suppose they are lazy enough not to remove the cover and scan you document page by page with OCR software.

Answer (score 0):

Any text in a PDF can be converted to any other textual format.

You may try rendering the information you want to put into PDF as an image, then insert the image into the PDF.

This way, when the PDF is read, the image data is gotten. Although this may still be converted into any format if the converter is persistent, it makes them do more work.

Answer (score -1):

To disable converting PDF in any other format you can use for example **PDFTK** command line, you can find it [here](http://www.silicongadget.com/internet/security/password-lock-pdf-files-with-pdftk/2059/)
It will prompt a password when user try to print your PDF document *(consider converting format is also a printing mechanism)*

**command line**

```
pdftk source.pdf output destination.pdf user_pw password
```

So to use it in PHP do not forget to add PDFTK to your PATH environment variable, set access authorizations and restart your web server

**EDIT**
you can use `shell_exec()`

```
<?php
// ... 
shell_exec('pdftk source.pdf output destination.pdf user_pw password');
?>
```

Comment: If the password specified is the "user" password (in PDF context), it means that this password has to be provided when the document is opened. The password to restrict capabilities is the "owner" password. Among those restrictions is printing and page extraction. Converting to Word is page extraction. The problem with those passwords is that a non-well-behaving application can simply ignore them. So, the question is whether this simple command line command will provide sufficient protection.