# While creating image from PDF using imagick I get the following error , Can anybody help to fix it

Tags: php, imagick

I'm using the following code

```
  $imagick = new Imagick();
// Reads image from PDF
$imagick->readImage('sample.pdf');
// Writes an image or image sequence Example- converted-0.jpg, converted-1.jpg
$imagick->writeImages('converted.jpg', false);
```

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ImagickException' with message 'UnableToOpenBlob `sample.pdf': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2702' in D:\xampp\htdocs\full_delay\fulcrum\www\www.axis.com\app\imagick\imagick-test.php:15 Stack trace: #0 D:\xampp\htdocs\full_delay\fulcrum\www\www.axis.com\app\imagick\imagick-test.php(15): Imagick->readimage('sample.pdf') #1 {main} thrown in D:\xampp\htdocs\full_delay\fulcrum\www\www.axis.com\app\imagick\imagick-test.php on line 15

Answer (score 1):

You should provide fullpath of your file. Like error said, there is no file `sample.pdf` in the directory where your code is executed.

Set a path like this:

```php
$imagick = new Imagick();
// Reads image from PDF
$imagick->readImage('D:\xampp\htdocs\full_delay\fulcrum\www\www.axis.com\app\imagick\sample.pdf');
// Writes an image or image sequence Example- converted-0.jpg, converted-1.jpg
$imagick->writeImages('converted.jpg', false);
```

Where `D:\xampp\htdocs\full_delay\fulcrum\www\www.axis.com\app\imagick\sample.pdf` is the path of your file.

Comment: My error got cleared , but I did't got any output. the browser says "The connection was reset"

Comment: I haven't used Imagick since a while. I think your code is incomplete. Take a look on this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9227014/convert-pdf-to-jpeg-with-php-and-imagemagick or the manual: https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php