# imagick multiple pdfs to jpg with php

Tags: php, pdf, jpeg, imagick

I need to convert all PDFs file of a directory into jpgs.

Like:

1.pdf
2.pdf
3.pdf

into

1.jpg
2.jpg
3.jpg

With this script I can find all PDFs.

```
$dir_name = "";
$pdfs = glob($dir_name."*.pdf");
foreach($pdfs as $pdf) {
   echo $pdf;
}
```

But how can I convert multiple files?

```
$imagick = new Imagick();
$imagick->setResolution(300, 300);
$imagick->readImage('???');
$imagick->writeImages('???', false);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert PDF to JPEG with PHP and ImageMagick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9227014/convert-pdf-to-jpeg-with-php-and-imagemagick)