# How to check if a pdf file is blank using PHP?

Tags: php, pdf

How can one check if a page in a PDF file is totally blank with PHP?

This can be done with Smalot PDFparser if your PDF file has text in it. On the other hand, if your file has no text but images, then PDFparser is no help. It cannot detect images.

I did a lot of online searching but could not find a solution.

Comment: Why do you need that in the first place?

Comment: @Olivier Trying to write a PHP script to remove blank pages from a large pdf file that has over 1K pages. Plus, there will be more files like this.

Comment: You could [convert to PNG/JPG using ImageMagick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9227014/convert-pdf-to-jpeg-with-php-and-imagemagick), and then scan that image for a certain threshold of pixles that are not background colored.

Comment: If there is only a page number, is it a bank page?

Comment: @Olivier There are no page numbers, no text of any kind, only images on some of the pages and lots of blank pages.

Comment: I have seen this kind of problem but solved it using pdftk. What are you using?

Comment: @Adi I need to do it with PHP.

Comment: Do you mean you only want to use PHP alone and no libraries? since pdftk is kind of a library you can use with PHP

Comment: @Adi A PHP library would be OK like Smalot PDFparser which unfortunately cannot detect images. Pdftk is an external program, if I am not mistaken, that can be run on the command line. You can probably execute it from inside the PHP but that is not the kind of approach I am looking for.

Comment: How about using TCPDF? You can remove blank pages using that too

Comment: @Adi It can work if TCPDF could parse existing PDF files and detect blank pages. I'll have to check that.

Comment: it should try, `$pdf = new TCPDF(); $pdf->setSourceFile($inputPdf);` but make sure you add this `require_once('tcpdf/tcpdf.php');`

Comment: Thanks for TCPDF and poppler suggestions. I'll look into them, probably tomorrow.

Comment: @Adi TCPDF can't parse a PDF. `setSourceFile()` comes from FPDI.

Comment: @Olivier my apologies regarding the function usage. but this true right https://tcpdf.org/docs/srcdoc/TCPDF/classes-TCPDF-PARSER/#:~:text=TCPDF_PARSER%20This%20is%20a%20PHP%20class%20for%20parsing%20PDF%20documents.?

Comment: @Adi There is a PDF parser [here](https://github.com/tecnickcom/tc-lib-pdf-parser) indeed, but it's not TCPDF. It's another library.

Comment: @Olivier oh interesting there are so many then. I believe it's a choice now as to which to choose whichever satisfies most of the needs with less workarounds for other missing functionality.

Comment: *"no text of any kind, only images"* Is there exactly 1 image on non-empty pages? If so, you could just extract all the images (assuming you get them in the correct order).

Comment: @Olivier Yes, it is one image on every non-blank page.