# ImageMagick PDF to JPGs sometimes results in black background

Tags: pdf, imagemagick, jpeg

I have the following:

```
ghostscript-fonts-5.50-24
ImageMagick-6.7.2-1
ghostscript-9.02-1
```

Which I use to create a series of JPGs for each page using:

```
convert -density 175 -colorspace sRGB test.pdf -resize 50% -quality 95 test.jpg
```

When I run this on my windows machine all appears to work ok, but on our linux server we get the black background problem.

The resulting JPGs have a black background rendering the image un-readable, what am I missing or is there something I should be doing to correct this?

I've been all over google for days but each suggestion doesnt seem to work for me.

Any help is much appreciated, thanks in advance :)

**EDIT**

Just noticed this output when converting one of the PDFs that produces the black background:

```
**** Warning: Fonts with Subtype = /TrueType should be embedded.
             The following fonts were not embedded:
                    Arial
                    Arial,Bold
                    Arial,BoldItalic
**** This file had errors that were repaired or ignored.
**** The file was produced by:
**** >>>> Microsoft« Word 2010 <<<<
**** Please notify the author of the software that produced this
**** file that it does not conform to Adobe's published PDF
**** specification.
```

This seems related but as we don't have control over how the PDFs are produced we need some way of fixing this server side.

Thanks again

Comment: _Please notify the author of the software_ - heh, good luck with that `;-)`.

Comment: I wonder, would setting the `-background` colour help here? Maybe you need to set it to white?

Comment: I've managed to get it working by converting to PNG instead of JPG as they support transparency. Thanks for the help

Comment: Great. Pop your solution in the answer box below, if you would - you can even award yourself the tick! `:)`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1903841/imagemagick-pdf-to-jpeg-conversion-results-in-green-square-where-image-should-be may be related...

Comment: Yes, from pdf to jpg was a problem.  pdf to png worked.  pdf to gif worked and made a much smaller file.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Simple fix to this issue is to use an image format that supports transparency, such as png.

So:

```
convert -density 175 -colorspace sRGB test.pdf -resize 50% -quality 95 test.png
```

Problem solved :)

Comment: @rogerdpack, try http://tinypng.org/ or [Improved pngquant](https://github.com/pornel/improved-pngquant). You know how you can save a PNG as an indexed color image and it looks just like a GIF? Well, it turns out you can do the indexed color palette *and* preserve the alpha transparency. The result is a vastly compressed PNG that looks almost identical to the original. [JPEG 2000](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG_2000) was supposed to have alpha transparency support for JPEGs, but support the file format never really gained traction in web browsers.

Comment: If anyone using RMagick and want to map above solution into RMagick then use this Doc: Magick Command Options and Their Equivalent Methods in RMagick - https://rmagick.github.io/optequiv.html

Answer (score 114):

Ran into this one today, found this:

https://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=20234

Based on that, these should all work:

- `-flatten`
- `-alpha flatten`
- `-alpha remove`

I'm currently using the below for my specific case which works great:

```
convert -thumbnail "1280x800>" -density 300 -background white -alpha remove in.pdf out.jpg
```

Comment: If you want to split a multi-page PDF into several JPEGs per page, `-flatten` will not work, as it will mash all pages into a single image. 
`-alpha flatten` or `-alpha remove` is the way to go.

Comment: For C# you can use: image.Alpha(AlphaOption.Remove);

Comment: I am converting PDF to TIFF (for faxing) and was using "-alpha off" by default, but would see all black pages if the page had PDF form fields or signatures pasted in as transparent PNG's.  Changing to "-alpha remove" worked as florian suggests.  I played with other alpha values but remove is the way to go.

Comment: If anyone using RMagick and want to map above solution into RMagick then use this Doc: Magick Command Options and Their Equivalent Methods in RMagick - https://rmagick.github.io/optequiv.html

Comment: For rmagick what worked for me was changing the image_type. `image.image_type=Magick::ImageType.new('TrueColorType', 1)`

Answer (score 4):

If you want a high quality result, use this command:

```
convert -density 700 input.pdf -resize 25% -append  -quality 98 -alpha remove output.jpg
```

For windows users, use `magick` instead of `convert`

Comment: it helped me! thank you, just to follow up. use magick convert for the latest version.

Comment: Just found that `-density 700` has to come *before* `input.pdf`, or else it is ignored.